# What tag to create for environmental control systems?

Tags: discussion, tags

Some variations that came to mind (not limited to those):

- ecs
- environmental-control-system / -systems

  - more professional but encompasses the existing [acs-pressurization](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/acs-pressurization)* **x6**
- climate-control
- cabin-temperature

  - in line with the existing [cabin-pressure](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cabin-pressure) **x132**
- *something else* (including renaming/merging/synonymizing existing tags)

* [acs-pressurization](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/acs-pressurization) may *not* cover planes with just cabin heat, and its usage guidance says "Air conditioning system **and/or** cabin pressurization", but it's unclear from the tag alone (ACS is possibly not a commonly used aviation acronym)

Along with your recommendation, explain **why** please.

---

Example questions that need such a tag:

- [How does a C208B's climate control system that utilizes bleed air for cabin heat work?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/89283/14897)
- [If the cabin temperature controller does not function, does the pilot have to make an emergency landing?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/27214/14897)
- [Why is the temperature of the cabin so low during a flight?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/41026/14897)

Answer (score 1):

I would propose using the header names of the [ATA chapters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATA_100). The relevant one here would be ATA 21, Air Conditioning.

The wiki lists the chapters and sub-chapters as:

> 21 AIR CONDITIONING
>
> - 00 Air Conditioning - General
> - 10 Compression
> - 20 Distribution
> - 30 Pressurization Control
> - 40 Heating
> - 50 Cooling
> - 60 Temperature Control
> - 70 Moisture/Air Contaminant Control

indicating that all climate systems functionality such as pressurisation, heating/cooling and cabin air compression all fall under the header of Air Conditioning.

An event like sudden cabin pressure loss due to a cracked fuselage is not [aircraft-systems] related and would not fall under the Air Conditioning tag, so a [cabin-pressure] tag would be useful.

Comment: It sounds counterintuitive, doesn't it. A question on sudden pressure loss due to  a cracked fuselage would not fall under Air Conditioning, so no I would not suggest synonymising the two tags. The sub-chapter list was purely to illustrate that all climate systems functionality falls under Air Conditioning according to official terminology.